# Laravel - list out reserved and available tables

Tags: laravel

**Case:**

I am working on a Restaurant project and is trying to list out reserved tables and available tables in a view. I am able to list out all reserved tables in a specific time and date, but not able to list out the remaining tables that isn't reserved.

**Tables**

I have a order table like this:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/208543/2
```

and a resturant tables table:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7db56/1
```

**Laravel code**

I have the following code for listing all reserved table:

```
$reserved = Order::where('date',$request->input('date'))
                ->orWhere('time', $request->input('time'))
                ->leftJoin('tables', 'ref_tableID', '=', 'tables.tableID')
                ->get();
```

This code works fine, but when I try for example to change the operator to != 
 it isn't working.

**Models**

Table model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Table extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['tableID','number','description','status','capacity'];

       public function orders(){
           return $this->hasMany(App\Order);
       }
}
```

Order table:

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['orderID','time','date','personID','cartID','foodID','drinkID','tableID'];

    public function tables(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Table');
    }

}
```

Can someone please help me listing out remaining tables that isn't reserved ?

Comment: What represents a *reserved* table? The order record?

Comment: Stick to conventions for table and column names, that is the primary key named `id`, and “snake_case” (i.e. `cart_id`). It’ll make your life easier when working with Eloquent models and relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to fetch are records that do not have orders where orders are reservations. If so, the `doesntHave` method would be of use to you.

I don't quite understand your table logic nor what defines a reserved table and why you're manually left joining instead of making direct use of the relationship, but this method applies to find records which don't have relation records, so try and apply this to your logic.

`$available_tables = Table::doesntHave('orders')->get();`

Or something more specific to your needs:

```
$available_tables = Order::doesntHave('tables')
                         ->where('date',$request->input('date'))
                         ->orWhere('time', $request->input('time'))
                         ->get();
```

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply. I noticed my explanation was quite confusing especially when my model was wrong due to copy paste. Anyway I managed to read up on your doesntHave suggestion and my problem is solved!